# Конфликт validator w3с и включений PHP

Tags: php, валидация

Включения `<?php    ?>` не проходят валидацию. Возможно это и нормально, но неприятно. 
Проверка на валидность страницы может осуществляться двумя способами. Отправка адрес страницы и отправка кода страницы.
Понятно, что при отправке адреса страницы проблем с валидацией нет. Поскольку валидатор просто не видит включений РНР. 
Но кто как, а для меня это довольно неудобно, отлавливать ошибки с уже размещённого на сайте или на локальном хосте ресурса. Гораздо удобнее это делать прямо из редактора. Вот здесь и возникает проблема нахождения несуществующих ошибок.
Вопрос в следующем, может я чего не знаю, и можно настроить редактор, например, «Dreamweaver» так, чтобы он отдавал уже обработанную сервером страницу на валидатор, либо на самой странице можно, что-то указать непосредственно для валидатора, что бы он не ругался?
Или вообще просто подождать и консорциум сам решит эту проблему?

Comment: А разве Dreamweaver - не для клиент-сайда?

Comment: А просто не обращать на них внимания? Ты же знаешь, что это не ошибки и на клиенте этих тегов не будет, будет только хтмл код

Comment: Как бы да. Но есть один момент. Валидатор воспринимает теги на полном серьёзе, и уже внутри включения начинает находит ошибки, например незакрытый тег, и т. д. Если включение обширное, то сбивает с толку и идёт потеря времени. Кроме того, появляется возможность пропуска реальной ошибки и как следствие пропадание кроссбраузерности. Т. е. в твоём просмотрщике всё хорошо, а в Сафари всё перекосится, например.

Comment: Наверняка эта проблема решена консорциумом. Вот только узнать бы как. Тут явно нужен специалист близкий к их кругам, который бы мог дать обстоятельный ответ.

Comment: И Dreamweaver отправляет код страницы необработанный сервером. Может, что то в настойках не так?

Comment: В общем сам себе и отвечаю. Если вы поклонник безошибочной валидации и вынуждены проверять исходный код, то как вариант можно использовать следующую конструкцию: <!--<?php echo '-->'; 
  echo '<!--'?>--> пояснять наверно нет нужды.